# MUI className using makeStyles does not apply the css implementation, but style does?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have my code here and the width in 'DisplayPage' useStyle does not work. However, when I apply style={{width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`}} then it starts working. It is quite confusing that to some it works but there are some cases that they don't work. Not really sure what is the factor that determines which styles to be implemented?

How do I know when makeStyles will be applied or not?

```
const drawerWidth = 240;

// MUI Setting
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  displayPage: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      marginLeft: drawerWidth,
      height: `100%`,
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('xs')]: {
      width: '100%',
      height: `calc(100% - 64px)`,
    },
  },
}));

      <div
        className={classes.displayPage}
        style={{ width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)` }}
      >


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: You need to switch the order of the two media queries. `up('xs')` will match anything that also matches `up('sm')`. When both match, the last one will win.

Comment: Thank yooou so much! learning new things every day!